# Splitting up a linear model in R: contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels

Tags: r, formula, lm

My dataset is too big/formula too complicated to run `biglm`, `fastLm`, `speedlm` or `lm` in one go. Therefor I'm down to splitting up my dataset in smaller pieces and performing an `update` for every 50.000 rows.

A simplified version of what I'm using. Replacing the iris dataset by my own.

```
library(speedglm)
chunk1 <- iris[1:10,]
chunk2 <- iris[11:20,]
chunk3 <- iris[21:30,]
lmfit  <- speedlm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Species, chunk1)

for (i in list(11,20, 21:30)){
  lmfit2 <- updateWithMoreData(lmfit, iris[i,])
}
lmfit2
```

Splitting up the model gets me the following error:

```
Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) : 
contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels
```

- Changing the formula is not an option, as each effect is relevant.
- Making the 'smaller pieces' bigger is not an option, as the dataset will get too big and slow down performance
- I have no clue which columns are erroneous, it may also differ at times which columns will give this error.

What are my options?

Comment: Split the data differently. `iris[1:10,]` contains only one `Species`.

Comment: @Ronald I have no clue which columns are erroneous, it may also differ at times which columns will give this error. I also have this problem for a whole bunch of different formulas so figuring out how to split each column differently is not really an option. There can also be multiple factors with only one level at a time.

Comment: Have you factored the data before you split it? Otherwise you may get different levels in each split, which will cause the error.

Comment: @JohannesNE No, I've basically got my code as in the example above, will read up about factoring

Comment: @JohannesNE I have been trying to work out how to factor the data, without success so far.. I have made a [simplified example here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33143257/factoring-for-linear-models-create-lm-with-one-factor). Hopefully you can help me out:)

Comment: Se my answer in your new post.