# Factoring for linear models - Create lm with one factor

Tags: r, lm, factoring

This question is a more specific and simplified version of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33117997/splitting-up-a-linear-model-in-r-contrasts-can-be-applied-only-to-factors-with).

The dataset I'm using is too large for a single `lm` or `speedlm` calculation.
I want to split up my data set in smaller pieces but in doing this, one(or more) of the columns only contains one [factor](http://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~s133/factors.html).
The code below is the mininum to reproduce my example. On the bottom of the question I will put my testing script for those interested.

```
library(speedglm)

iris$Species <- factor(iris$Species)
i <- iris[1:20,]
summary(i)
speedlm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Species , i)
```

This gets me the following error:

```
Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) : 
  contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels
```

I have tried to factorize `iris$Species` but without success. I really don't have a clue how I could fix this now.

***How can I include `Species` into the model?*** (without increasing the sample size)

Edit:
I know I only have one level: "setosa" but I still need it included in the linear model because I will update the model with more factors eventually, as seen in the example script below

---

For those interested, here is an example script of what I will use for my actual dataset:

```
library(speedglm)

testfunction <- function(start.i, end.i) {
  return(iris[start.i:end.i,])
}

  lengthdata <- nrow(iris)
  stepsize <- 20

## attempt to factor
  iris$Species <- factor(iris$Species)

## Creates the iris dataset in split parts
  start.i <- seq(0, lengthdata, stepsize)
  end.i   <- pmin(start.i + stepsize, lengthdata)

  dat <- Map(testfunction, start.i + 1, end.i)

## Loops trough the split iris data
  for (i in dat) {
    if (!exists("lmfit")) {
      lmfit  <- speedlm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Species , i)
    } else if (!exists("lmfit2")) {
      lmfit2 <- updateWithMoreData(lmfit, i)
    } else {
      lmfit2 <- updateWithMoreData(lmfit2, i)
    }
  }
  print(summary(lmfit2))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be a better way, but if you reorder your rows, each split will contain more levels, and therefore not cause the error. I created a random order, but you might want to do a more systematic way.

```
library(speedglm)

testfunction <- function(start.i, end.i) {
    return(iris.r[start.i:end.i,])
}

lengthdata <- nrow(iris)
stepsize <- 20

## attempt to factor
iris$Species <- factor(iris$Species)

##Random order
set.seed(1)
iris.r <- iris[sample(nrow(iris)),]

## Creates the iris dataset in split parts
start.i <- seq(0, lengthdata, stepsize)
end.i   <- pmin(start.i + stepsize, lengthdata)

dat <- Map(testfunction, start.i + 1, end.i)

## Loops trough the split iris data
for (i in dat) {
    if (!exists("lmfit")) {
        lmfit  <- speedlm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Species , i)
    } else if (!exists("lmfit2")) {
        lmfit2 <- updateWithMoreData(lmfit, i)
    } else {
        lmfit2 <- updateWithMoreData(lmfit2, i)
    }
}
print(summary(lmfit2))
```

**Edit**
Instead of the random order, you can use modulo division to generate a spred out index vector in a systematic way:

```
spred.i <- seq(1, by = 7, length.out = 150) %% 150 + 1
iris.r <- iris[spred.i,]
```